# Looping XSD 1.1 assert

Tags: xml, loops, xsd, assert

I'm doing my best to validate XML document with XSD 1.1 schema but there's no way. I've simplified my sample and looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:vc="http://www.w3.org/2007/XMLSchema-versioning" elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <xs:element name="message1">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element type="xs:string" name="indexmessage"/>
                <xs:element name="rows" maxOccurs="1">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element name="row" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                                <xs:complexType>
                                    <xs:sequence>
                                        <xs:element name="code">
                                            <xs:simpleType>
                                                <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                                                    <xs:minLength value="1"/>
                                                    <xs:maxLength value="16"/>
                                                </xs:restriction>
                                            </xs:simpleType>
                                        </xs:element>
                                        <xs:element name="totalquantity">
                                            <xs:simpleType>
                                                <xs:restriction base="xs:decimal">
                                                    <xs:fractionDigits value="2"/>
                                                </xs:restriction>
                                            </xs:simpleType>
                                        </xs:element>
                                        <xs:element name="attachments" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
                                            <xs:complexType>
                                                <xs:sequence>
                                                    <xs:element name="attachment" minOccurs="1"
                                                  maxOccurs="unbounded">
                                                        <xs:complexType>
                                                            <xs:sequence>
                                                                <xs:element name="quantity">
                                                                    <xs:simpleType>
                                                                        <xs:restriction base="xs:decimal">
                                                                            <xs:fractionDigits value="2"/>
                                                                        </xs:restriction>
                                                                    </xs:simpleType>
                                                                </xs:element>
                                                            </xs:sequence>
                                                        </xs:complexType>
                                                    </xs:element>
                                                </xs:sequence>                                                                                              
                                            </xs:complexType>
                                        </xs:element>
                                    </xs:sequence>                                  
                                    <xs:assert test="every $r in row/attachments/attachment satisfies eq(row/quantitytotal, sum($r/quantity)"/>
                                </xs:complexType>
                            </xs:element>
                        </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

So what I want to implement in xs:assertion is that quantitytotal must be equals to the sum of the quantity of "row attachments". I've seen many samples using "every" keyword but never works. Here's an XSD sample also:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<message1>                  
    <indexmessage>02</indexmessage>     
    <rows>              
        <row>           
            <code>1789</code>       
            <totalquantity>3</totalquantity>
            <attachments>
                <attachment>
                    <quantity>2</quantity>
                </attachment>
                <attachment>
                    <quantity>1</quantity>
                </attachment>
            </attachments>
        </row>
        <row>
         ...
        </row>              
    </rows>             
</message1>
```

Assert in this sample must be true cause 2+1=3 and it's the reason why I'm trying to implement xs:assert looping all rows.

Many thanks ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to "loop" through `row` elements.  Your assertion is at the `row` level already; from there, let `sum()` add all the `quantity` values:

```
<xs:assert test="sum(attachments/attachment/quantity) = totalquantity"/>
```

This assertion will be checked for each `row` automatically.

Here is the above assertion in context in your XSD:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
           xmlns:vc="http://www.w3.org/2007/XMLSchema-versioning" 
           vc:minVersion="1.1" 
           elementFormDefault="qualified">
  <xs:element name="message1">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element type="xs:string" name="indexmessage"/>
        <xs:element name="rows" maxOccurs="1">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="row" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="code">
                      <xs:simpleType>
                        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                          <xs:minLength value="1"/>
                          <xs:maxLength value="16"/>
                        </xs:restriction>
                      </xs:simpleType>
                    </xs:element>
                    <xs:element name="totalquantity">
                      <xs:simpleType>
                        <xs:restriction base="xs:decimal">
                          <xs:fractionDigits value="2"/>
                        </xs:restriction>
                      </xs:simpleType>
                    </xs:element>
                    <xs:element name="attachments" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
                      <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                          <xs:element name="attachment" minOccurs="1"
                                      maxOccurs="unbounded">
                            <xs:complexType>
                              <xs:sequence>
                                <xs:element name="quantity">
                                  <xs:simpleType>
                                    <xs:restriction base="xs:decimal">
                                      <xs:fractionDigits value="2"/>
                                    </xs:restriction>
                                  </xs:simpleType>
                                </xs:element>
                              </xs:sequence>
                            </xs:complexType>
                          </xs:element>
                        </xs:sequence>                                                                                              
                      </xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>
                  </xs:sequence>                                  
                  <xs:assert test="sum(attachments/attachment/quantity) = totalquantity"/>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your deep nesting makes it very difficult to see the logic here, but if I read it right your xs:assert is part of the definition of element row, and the row element does not have a child called row, therefore row/attachments/attachment will select nothing.

And by the way, your "so as you can see" is incredibly presumptious. Do you really expect us to see what you are trying to achieve by reading code that fails to achieve it?

Comment: Thanks Michael, i'll answer myself with a better explanation.